# how to instantiate objects inside the class to be tested is an abstract class in Junit testing?

Tags: junit, java-8, guice, autowired

I have a class below for which I want to write a unit test

```
abstract class ProductImpl{
   @Inject DataServices ds; // using Guice 

   public Response parse(String key, Long value){
      Response res = ds.getResponseObject(); // Response object is created using DataServices object
      res.id = key;
      res.code = value;

   }
}
```

And I have a test as below

```
class ProductImplTest{

@InjectMocks ProductImpl impl;
Map<String, Long> map;

@Before
 map.put("abc", 10L);
 map.put("xyz", 11L);
}

@Test
public void test(){
  for(String key: map.keySet()){
    Response res = impl.parse(key, map.get(key));
    // and check if fields of Response object are set correctly i.e res.id is abc and value is 10L
  }
}
```

But when i debug the test and control goes to parse method , **DataServices object ds** is null. How to instantiate this object through test . I do not want to use mocking, I want real response objects to be created and test the values set in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ProductImplTest {
    @Mock DataService dService;
    @InjectMocks ProductImpl sut;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ResponseObject ro = new ResponseObject();

        String string = "string";
        Long longVal = Long.valueOf(123);

        sut.parse("string", longVal);

        verify(dService).getResponseObject();
        assertThat(ro.getId()).isEqualTo("string");
        // you should use setters (ie setId()), then you can mock the ResponseObject and use
        // verify(ro).setId("string");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

With `ResponseObject` being an abstract class or preferably an interface, you'd have

```
interface ResponseObject {
    void setId(String id);
    String getId();
    // same for code
}
```

and in your test

```
@Test public void test() {
    ResponseObject ro = mock(ResponseObject.class);
    // ... same as above, but
    verify(dService).getResponseObject();
    verify(ro).setId("string"); // no need to test getId for a mock
}
```

Comment: Thank you.How would it look if my ProductImpl was an abstract class

Comment: @tech_ques added test for a `ResponseObject` interface.

Comment: @daniu OP is referring to `ProductImpl` being abstract

Comment: Oh, I see. That depends on what's abstract about it. It's probably a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with constructor injection:

```
class ProductImpl{
   DataServices ds;

   @Inject 
   public ProductImpl(DataServices ds) {
     this.ds = ds;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.How would it look if my ProductImpl was an abstract class

Comment: You can't create instance of Abstract Class, so it doesn't make sense to test it. Of course if you have a real class that extends it - then you should test a real class